# How to check to state of controls created dynamically using itemscontrol after naming them in the itemscontrol wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

For my code, I've created multiple control of the same type (i.e.  Checkbox) using itemscontrol bound to a class "MyClass". I've named the checkbox control as "checkControl". Now, as I've multiple checkbox control created in the UI, I want to check their state and differentiate among them. How should I proceed? I'm thinking of using findvisualchild & findvisualparent? But, I don't have any idea how to use it?

```
<ItemsControl Name="myList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="30,80,10,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border x:Name="tempBorder" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" Margin="0,-30,-60,-30"
                                            Background="LightGray">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" Margin="0">
                        <StackPanel Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkControl" Margin="7,7,0,0" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <Image Source="/Images/myimage.png" Margin="0,10,0,0"></Image>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Disk}" FontFamily="roboto" FontSize="14"/>
                                            <Rectangle Width="340" Height="1" Margin="0,5,5,5" Fill="Black"/>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                                <Run Text="Item:" FontFamily="roboto" FontSize="14"/>
                                                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat=' {0} Jr.'}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Orange"
                                                                 FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightGray" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="765"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="Select the Option:" Margin="15,7,0,7" FontFamily="roboto"/>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="comboControl" Margin="15,5,0,7" Width="750" SelectionChanged="comboControl_SelectionChanged"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

For My Backend C# Code:
Class

```
 public class MyClass
{
    public string Disk { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public MyClass(string album, string name)
    {
        this.Disk = album;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

In my Xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> StudentDisk { get; set; }
//somecode
StudentDisk.Add(new MyClass("Disk 4 ", "John"));   //For populating
//somecode
myList.ItemsSource = StudentDisk;
```

Comment: “For my code...”, what code?? Please show it.

Comment: Bind itemssouce to an observablecollection of some class with all the properties you need for each item. Bind a public bool property from that to ischecked. Use the itemtemplate to template these into your checkboxes. Then you can use linq on that collection to pick out tge checked ones and do whatever. Work with data rather than the ui.

Comment: @Andy I didn't understand completely! Can you please help me with an example

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to differentiate checkBoxes by their DataContext, which should be unique:

```
void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var item = (MyClass)checkbox.DataContext;
    MessageBox.Show(item.Disk + " " + item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hi @ASh  I need to get the ischecked property when I'm moving to next UI on the click of next button, So, This doesn't completely answer it and so I need to access all the checkbox using visualtree (which I'm not able to do as of now) or by associating ischecked property with the binding class!!

Comment: I'm able to access the first checkbox control using visualparent and visualchild and not all!

Comment: why don't you create `bool IsChecked {get;set;}` property in MyClass, and bind CheckBox.isChecked to it `IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"`? then you can get all checked items from StudentDisk collection, without messing with visual tree, which doesn't contain all items anyway because of virtualization

Comment: Thanks !! I had tried it earlier but what I missed out was Binding Mode needs to be set to two way binding or binding to the source as I wanted the UI changes to be reflected at backend!!